# scrollIntoView not working: refreshes the page

Tags: html, css, js-scrollintoview

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" class="hero-btn" onClick="document.getElementById('middle').scrollIntoView();">Get Started</a>
<div id="middle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hero-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
    background: #f44336;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

I was expecting it to scroll to my div. But it scrolls and then refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The refresh is due to the `<a>` link default behavior. Give it the attribute `href="#"` and to prevent automatic default scroll add `return false;` on the onclick listener like that:

```css
.hero-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hero-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
    background: #f44336;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hero-btn" onClick="document.getElementById('middle').scrollIntoView(); return false;">Get Started</a>
<div id="middle"></div>
```

I haven't tested it but it should works